# JSON equivalent of XML

Tags: json

I want to create JSON file equivalent to below mentioned XML file

```
<Data>
    <EE  id="1001">
        <a1>50</a1>
        <a2>100</a2>
        <a3>25</a3>
        <a4>10</a4>
        <a5>1</a5>
        <a6>1</a6>
    </EE >
    <EE  id="1002">
        <a1>75</a1>
        <a2>60</a2>
        <a3>35</a3>
        <a4>20</a4>
        <a5>1</a5>
        <a6>1</a6>
    </EE >
    <EE  id="1003">
        <a1>100</a1>
        <a2>80</a2>
        <a3>50</a3>
        <a4>40</a4>
        <a5>10</a5>
        <a6>10</a6>
    </EE >
</Data>
```

What will be the JSON equivalent of above xml?

Also please share the best Guide/Tutorial on JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "1001": {
        "a": [
            50,
            100,
            25,     
            10,
            1,
            1
        ]
    },
    "1002": {
        "a": [
            75,
            60,
            35,
            20,
            1,
            1
        ]
    },
    "1003": {
        "a": [
            100,
            80,
            40,
            50,
            10,
            10
        ]
    }
}
```